# Почему не работает и выдает ошибки С2923 С2061 С2238

Tags: c++

```
template <typename _Ty, typename Allocator = std::allocator<_Ty> >
class C
{
private:

    struct Node
    {
        _Ty Data;
        Node* Next;
    };
    Allocator::rebind<C<_Ty>::Node>::other a;
    Node* head;
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() {}
};

int main()
{
    C<int> c;
    return 0;
};
```

Выдает ошибку c rebind : Ошибка C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "other".
Ничего не понимаю.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка

```
template <typename _Ty, typename Allocator = std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Ty>> >
class C
{
private:

    struct Node
    {
        _Ty Data;
        Node* Next;
    };
    Allocator::rebind_alloc<C<_Ty>::Node> a;

    Node* head;
public:
    C() {}
    ~C() {}
};

int main()
{
    allocator_traits<allocator<int>>::rebind_alloc<char> a;
    C<int> c;
    return 0;
};
```

такая штука к сожалению тоже не работает и выдает :

Ошибка  C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "rebind_alloc"

Comment: `...>::other` и `...>::Node` являются зависимыми именами и по-умолчанию парсятся как имя переменной или функции, чтобы этого избежать необходимо в начале добавить `typename`. Однако в данном случае это не особо поможет,  `std::allocator::rebind` устарел и удален из текущей версии языка. Также `C<_Ty>` может не совпадать с текущим экземпляром шаблона, а имена, начинающиеся с `_`, за которой идет заглавная буква, зарезервированы, а для `std::allocator` требуется соответствующий `include`, а `;` после окончания функции излишне.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вам нужно `typename allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<C::Node> a;`, но не уверен...

Comment: чот жутко сложно, но вроде осознал что надо думать в сторону allocator_traits

Comment: @Harry объясните, пожалуйста, как работает ключевое слово template в данной конструкции и, если не сложно, где про это можно дополнительно узнать

Comment: Увы, не разъясню, это я чисто по аналогии с имеющимся кодом сделал - потому и комментарий, а не ответ :). А так - рекомендую [эту книгу](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9500296-8-4.html).

Answer (score 1):

`...>::other` и `...>::Node` являются зависимыми именами и по-умолчанию парсятся как имя переменной или функции, чтобы этого избежать необходимо в начале добавить `typename`. Однако в данном случае это не особо поможет, `std::allocator::rebind` устарел и удален из текущей версии языка. Также `C<_Ty>` может не совпадать с текущим экземпляром шаблона, а имена, начинающиеся с `_`, за которой идет заглавная буква, зарезервированы, а для `std::allocator` требуется соответствующий `include`, а `;` после окончания функции излишне.